# JavaScript <a href> to a <div> and its children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I this simple website Im trying to develop, but I have never used Javascript before.

I have a menu that is based on href to div tags on my site to the different agreements with different companies. So when the user click a choice in the menu the right div item fades in.

Now I want to make the site more practical with google maps api for each company.
So I need to `<a href>` in the menu to display more than just one `<div>` item. I have tried to solve this by using a `<table>` inside the `<div>` item. Since I want to have the company description on the left hand og the google map + short description on the right hand. But now I have decided that I want to use `<div>` items with display properties instead of a `<table>` inside a `<div>` item.

Here is the code just made simple without the php code to gather info from DB:
http://jsfiddle.net/nerfux/546Jn/7/

As you see, category2 -> company3, is the messy solution I made. In the HTML code at `<div id='com-1'>` and `<div id='com-2'>`, I have commented out the solution I want to use.

So, a short way to say it: When I click a href to a div item, I want also to fadeIn all the `<div>` items underneath the `<div>` item I `<a href=*div id*>` to (regardless if they have an id or not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to hide the wrapping container (.content), and not the divs inside, you can just add `>` to the selector. It will only affect the div directly under .content.

So add `>` to
`$('.content div')`
like so
 `$('.content > div')`